# other elements are selected if the first is selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select elements that have specific attribute, but nothing is selected unless the first element of them is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".cards").append('<div class="card new" style="width: 20rem;">\
    <div class="layer"></div>\
        <div class="card-block">\
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>\
            <p class="card-text"></p>\
        </div>\
        <div class="card-block">\
            <div class="delete">Del</div>\
            <div class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#note">edit</div>\
        </div>\
    </div>');
    var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
    var text = $("#noteBody").val();
    var layer = $("#selected").css("background-color");
    $(".new .layer").css({"background-color": layer, "position": "absolute", "opacity": ".2", "top":"0", "left":"0", "width": "100%", "height": "100%"});
    $(".new h4").html(title);
    $(".new p").html(text);

    $(".card").removeClass("new");
});
// .toggleClass() didn't work here
$("main").on("click", ".card", function() {
    if($(this).css("border") == "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)") {
        $(this).css("border", "solid 2px black");
    } else {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)");
    }
});
//is there a problem below ?
$(".colors").click(function() {
if($(".card").length != 0 && $(".card").css("border").indexOf("2px") != -1)
    $('.card[style*="2px"]').find(".layer").css("background-color", $(this).val());
});
```

and I don't know why toggleClass() didn't work above.

Comment: This is basically how not to do things. Do not use CSS, especially colors, as conditions to do anything, add classes instead. Do not write large blocks of HTML inside your javascript.

Comment: I've changed my code and just added classes and used as conditions and it worked!, I don't know why I forget using classes a lot of time,thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes instead modify css properties directly.

```js
// Wrong

// .toggleClass() didn't work here
$("main").on("click", ".card", function() {
  if($(this).css("border") == "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)") {
    $(this).css("border", "solid 2px black");
  } else {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)");
  }
});

// Better.

/**
 * CSS:
 * .card { border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); }
 * .card.active {  border: 2px solid black; }
 */
$('.card').on('click', function () {
  // Remove class for all.
  $('.card').each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  // Add class for current element.
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.card').on('click', function (e) {
  var isActive = $(this).attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1;
  // Remove class for all.
  $('.card').forEach(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  // Add class for current element.
  if (!isActive) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```